# QtCreator add include in project by single click

Tags: qt-creator

I have found very cool possibilities in QtCreator which is:

- prolongate signature changes between declaration and definition for C++ methods,functions
- find symbols usage

Is it possible "append" include file for specific "type name" of "function"?

(Like Visual Studio VS assist plugin)